# Cannot browse from AWS instance to itself

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, iis

I created new AWS instance today and ran into a problem.
Browsing (HTTPS) from external machines to my AWS instance works fine. When I browse from instance itself, I receive "Site can't be reached". The site is on IIS and the DNS name is bound to all IPs of this instance ("All unassigned").

Running nslookup on the instance yielded, that I receive right external IP while browsing from the instance itself.

Maybe the problem is in my security group? I allowed HTTPS in this group, but should it take into account internal IP also? How should I configure security group it will allow this kind of browsing? I am missing something here.

Thank you!

Comment: can you access any other site from your instance?

Comment: Does it work with the private IP? AWS translates private to public IPs at the internet gateway, so if you're trying to resolve the public IP I would consider the security group. I expect it's something simple like that, or an instance based firewall. There's not enough information in your question to help much more, please do some diagnostics and edit your question if my suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexD yes, I can browse internet from the instance.

Comment: The simplest way is to add the domain name to your hosts file on that server and point to 127.0.0.1 so that your traffic goes only via localhost.